# Serilog "Maximum destructuring depth reached"

Tags: serilog

I've enabled SeriLog (latest version) Self-Logging and am seeing hundreds of messages that say

> Maximum destructuring depth reached

No idea what that means and whether it's a problem I need to worry about or not.

Does anyone know what triggers this message and whether I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data:

> Destructuring is the process of taking a complex .NET object and
>   converting it into a structure, which may later be represented as say,
>   a JSON object or XML blob

Sounds like you might have a ciruclar reference in some data you're logging so when Serilog tries to destructure it, it's running into a recursive loop.  Sounds like it has some code to detect this and stop the infinite recursion.  I suspect that's where this warning is coming from.

Comment: Not entirely sure it was a circular reference, but one of the objects I was adding via an Enricher was the source of the problem.

Comment: Note that it can come from the configuration new LoggerConfiguration().Destructure.ToMaximumDepth(3)

Comment: @Mr.T for me, it was the `WithExceptionDetails` enriched causing a recursive logging action.